# jquery not working in a div with a id

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I have this website, and I copied some Jquery from W3School to toggle a button hide on/off. But if I place this `<div>` and `<p>` tag in a div I made to function like a window. It just doesn't work. In the whole page it works except in that `<div id="BoxWithPhotoAndBtn">` How is this possible? Iam working in bootstrap, and in ASP.net.

```
 <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var phide = 'phide';

$("#bHide").click(function () {
    $("#phide").toggle();
}); 
});
</script>

<div class="container">

     <!-- Modal messageModel -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="messageModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblMessageTitle" CssClass="black" runat="server"></asp:Label></h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">

                    <p id="lblModelMessage" class="black" runat="server"></p>

                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

                             <!-- this works just fine
                            <p id="phide">This is a paragraph.</p>

<div id="bHide">Toggle between hide() and show()</div> -->


     <img runat="server" src="#" class="imgAvatarSmallPE" id="imgAvatarSmall" />
<div id="BoxWithPhotoAndBtn">
                             <!-- this doesn't work -->
                            <p id="phide">This is a paragraph.</p>

<div id="bHide">Toggle between hide() and show()</div>
    <!-- create account fot this person -->
    <div id="membershipBoxPE">Membership Card</div>
    <div id="membershipCardPE">

    </div>
    <h2 runat="server" id="fullName" class="fullNamePE"></h2>
    <div id="buttonInBox"> 



        <span id="glypiconUserColor" class="glyphicon glyphicon-user fontSizeGlyphiconPE"></span> <p class="pinBoxPE"> Create account for this person</p>
        <hr class="lineInBoxPE"/>
        <span id="glypiconClockColor" class="glyphicon glyphicon-time fontSizeGlyphiconPE"></span> <p class="pinBoxPE"> Trained 31 times this Month</p>
        <hr class="lineInBoxPE" />
    </div>
    <asp:Image runat="server" CssClass="imgLevelPatchPE" ID="imgLevelPatch" />
    <p class="logedInPPE">This Person has logged in 1 time</p>
</div>
```

**this is the copy i took it from**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("p").toggle();
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>This is a paragraph.</p>

<button>Toggle between hide() and show()</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Would you post the JQuery you've copied!?

Comment: Do you have the button in the dialog and you are trying to toggle the P tag in the parent page?

Comment: yeah the only problem is that it wont work if i put the p and div in the div with the id BoxWithPhotoAndBtn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are working `asp.net` controls, ID's are dynamically generated via asp.net engine ( unless your using `staticID` mode ). So they would not appear in the rendered DOM exactly the way you have them declared. In order to apply correct selectors on `asp.net` elements, you need to use server side expression using `ClientID` property.

For example :

```
 <img runat="server" src="#" class="imgAvatarSmallPE" id="imgAvatarSmall" />
```

can be accessed in jquery via :

```
var id = '#<%=imgAvatarSmall.ClientID%>';
$(id).hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have more than one **Button** and more than one **P tag** in your HTML, in your case you need to hide a specific **P tag** when a button is clicked so use specific control Id or class selector.

**Update your button as below**

```
 <button type="button" id="btnClose" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
```

**Change your JS to**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btnClose").click(function(){
        $("#phide").toggle();
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5vcL8xnv/) sample